# can a void pointer safely point to annother pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, void

This might be obvious but, can a void pointer safely point to another pointer? i.e. point to a type int *

```
int i = 5;
int *ip = &i;
void *vp = &ip;

int *nip = *(int **)vp;
int ni = *nip; // == 5?
```

EDIT: Sorry maybe I'm not being clear, I would like to know if a void pointer can POINT TO a section of memory that has the type of another pointer; without being a void **. just void *

Comment: `int *nip = *vp;` should be `int *nip = vp;`

Comment: nope, that would be the super obvious question, thanks for your contribution though.

Comment: `int *nip = *vp;` in that case the answer is obvious: you cannot dereference a `void *`. period.

Comment: ah yes, you are quite right, I should have casted it

Comment: edited above now, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can convert any object pointer to `void *` and back to the original pointer type without loss of information.

From the horse's mouth:

> (C99, 6.3.2.3p1) "A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any incomplete or object type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to void  and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer."

Comment: It can point to anything; there is nothing special about a pointer.

Comment: @jayjay `void *` can point to any object: so `int` or `int *` or even `int **`.

Comment: He means to say that, it can point to anything even a int** or an int* or a char***. Anything.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can point to *any* object type<sup>1</sup>. You can't actually *dereference* a void pointer since the compiler doesn't know the "real" type behind it. But the pointing aspect is fine.

From `C11 6.3.2.3 Pointers /1`:

> A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to *any* object type. A pointer to *any* object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

---

<sup>1/</sup> "Object type" does not include functions, the rules for converting function pointers are slightly more restrictive.

Comment: *Yes, it can point to any type* It can point to any *object type*. It is not guaranteed to hold function pointer types.

Comment: Edit regarding casting `const` types has been rolled back. In case you didn't notice, this was a C question, not a C++ one.